# Safe CLI - Installing Errors

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

I am using PIP 22.3.1 and Python 3.10

When running the "pip3 install -U safe-cli" command, it runs until it gets to the following step below and outputs the following errors:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pyethash

Building wheel for pyethash (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
      internal.c
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1831): warning C4710: 'int sprintf_s(char *const ,const size_t,const char *const ,...)': function not inlined
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1831): note: see declaration of 'sprintf_s'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
      io.c
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1831): warning C4710: 'int sprintf_s(char *const ,const size_t,const char *const ,...)': function not inlined
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1831): note: see declaration of 'sprintf_s'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
      io_win32.c
      c1: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'src/libethash/io_win32.c': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyethash
  Running setup.py clean for pyethash
Failed to build pyethash
Installing collected packages: pyethash, netaddr, mypy-extensions, lru-dict, cached-property, bitarray, websockets, urllib3, toolz, tabulate, six, pyrsistent, pygments, pycryptodome, protobuf, prompt-toolkit, packaging, multidict, idna, hexbytes, frozenlist, eth-typing, eth-hash, colorama, charset-normalizer, certifi, base58, attrs, async-timeout, yarl, requests, parsimonious, multiaddr, jsonschema, cytoolz, aiosignal, ipfshttpclient, eth-utils, eth-bloom, aiohttp, rlp, py-ecc, eth-keys, eth-abi, trie, eth-rlp, eth-keyfile, py-evm, eth-account, web3, safe-eth-py, safe-cli
  Running setup.py install for pyethash ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pyethash did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      C:\Python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
      internal.c
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1831): warning C4710: 'int sprintf_s(char *const ,const size_t,const char *const ,...)': function not inlined
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1831): note: see declaration of 'sprintf_s'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
      io.c
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1831): warning C4710: 'int sprintf_s(char *const ,const size_t,const char *const ,...)': function not inlined
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1831): note: see declaration of 'sprintf_s'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
      io_win32.c
      c1: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'src/libethash/io_win32.c': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyethash

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
'''
```

Comment: I managed to get 2 out of the three errors resolved.

Comment: I have managed to get it installed in Linux

Comment: What are we supposed to use for the <ETHEREUM_NODE_URL> portion, I have tried various URLs and i keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved at this time. Installed with no errors using Linux